# PCIe Not enough MMIO resources for SR-IOV

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, yocto, virtualization, pci-e

I'm trying to write a kernel module for an Intel FPGA design supporting PCIe SR-IOV and placed in the x16 PCIe slot of an IBase M991 Mainboard (**Q170 PCH**, VT-d activated in BIOS, Integrated graphics only mode enabled).
The CPU is an Intel Core **i7-6700TE**, which also supports virtualization.
Furthermore I'm using a Yocto - Morty Distribution (Linux **Kernel 4.19**) with the following Kconfigs enabled:

```
CONFIG_PCI_IOV=y
CONFIG_PCI_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_INTEL_IOMMU_SVM=y
CONFIG_PCI_REALLOC_ENABLE_AUTO=y
CONFIG_INTEL_IOMMU_DEFAULT_ON=y
CONFIG_IRQ_REMAP=y
CONFIG_IOMMU_DEFAULT_PASSTHROUGH=y
CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y
```

When doing all of this I see my driver loading (probe function gets called), but after calling `pci_enable_sriov` with the number of VF I want to activate I get the kernel message
**not enough MMIO resources for SR-IOV**
What am I doing wrong here? Is there an init function I need to call?
Many thanks for your help.

Edit: More information about the PCIe device:
1 PF, 8 VF
2 BARs (BAR0 and BAR2)
non prefetchable, 32 bit BARs
each BAR size is 4 kB (12bit)

Comment: The MMIO address range behind each root port and bridge is set up by the BIOS. I’m not sure, but maybe there is a BIOS setting to get it to block off enough MMIO space for the device and all of its VFs? Or maybe an “SR-IOV Enable” that tells it to look for the number of VFs supported by the device.

Comment: When I search for that message I get lots of hits. Are none of them helpful to you?

Comment: Sadly yes. The Kernelconfigs already take care of the provided kernel cmdline arguments like pci=realloc or intel_iommu=on. I also added them manually, but behaviour didn't change

Comment: @prl, PCIe is flexible in that sense. How by your opinion is Thunderbolt working? (It’s rhetorical) So, it is quite possible to get a bigger window as long as OS allows to rebuild the resource tree. Unfortunately I don’t believe v4.19 is capable of that, it’s quite old. My suggestion to OP is to update kernel to let’s say v5.10.y (if you want LTS) and try again.

Comment: Do you have a setting in your BIOS for "Above 4G decoding"? Perhaps enabling it might help. See https://superuser.com/questions/1239231/what-is-above-4g-decoding

Comment: @haggai_e My BIOS doesn't expose this setting. Is this neccessary for virtualization?

Comment: @0andriy I switched to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with kernel 5.8.0-50 and still get the same error

Comment: @Krustenkaese, I believe this setting is needed for the BIOS to allocate the SRIOV BAR. In theory you could still reallocate in the OS kernel.

Comment: @haggai_e I finally got a BIOS update and enabled SR-IOV and "Above 4G" support. Error stays the same.